# Socket.io client reconnects when an error is thrown in a listener function (without displaying the error!)

Tags: socket.io-1.0, engine.io

When I throw an error in a listener function;

```
socket = require('socket.io-client').connect 'http://localhost:8080'

socket.on 'an-event', ->
    throw new Error 'An error has occured'  # this is never shown!
    console.log 'hello?'                    # this is never logged!
    process.exit 1                          # this is never called!
```

the socket reconnects, and the error is never shown. Instead, the engine.io Tranport class throws a "*parser decode error*".

This way I cannot develop/debug the logic inside a listener function. Is there a solution/workaround for this?

Comment: This behaviour seems to come from this [bug](https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io-client/issues/326#issuecomment-49721284) in engine.io-client.